# reduce neo4j path query memory consumption

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following graph

```
  A1 A2 A3
   \/   /|
   /\  / |
  B1 B2  B3
```

Imagine I have many type A and many type B nodes and they can be connected like a full mesh network. Now when I do

```
match p=(a:A)--(b:B)
return p
```

My graph will produce millions of paths. This incurs too much memory overhead and I either need to bump the memory of neo4j container or somehow make this path query into smaller pieces. Now increasing memory is going to be problematic since the graph size can grow.

How can I break the above query into smaller steps (with each step a smaller memory footprint) so I can still get the complete result after multiple queries?

Comment: What do you do with the paths? do you simply stream them outside of Neo4j?

Comment: Yes, stream them outside and do further processing. I could maybe create a UDF instead of using the cypher query and have that UDF dump out part of the paths each time. I am open for suggestions, but i do need to send it out of neo4j.

Comment: Do you have access to the file system where neo4j is installed? You could use various APOC export functions that store streams as CSV or JSONs and batch those.

Comment: Yes, I do. Could you share the method more concretely?